# Cannot create FXML file in JavaFX project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.
IDE: (Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) and Scene builder 2.

---

I can't choose root element because as I understand it should be done.
This window I see when creating a file.
[image]

---

Maybe I incorrectly set the path to my Scene Builder executable.
[image]

How to solving this problem?
I did everything according to [instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/installation-guide/jfxsb-installation_2_0.htm).

---

Update 1: Not yet solved the problem, I'll use the [Idea IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html)

---

Update 2: Now i use Netbeans with JDK from ORACLE [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/netbeans/downloads/index.html). I chose the easiest way.

Comment: Are there any options available in the combo box next to root element? since there is an option to use `fx:root` this probably is just the choice of the Layout to use, which seems to be mandatory...

Comment: @fabian No options and when i click on the **fx:root** the problem is not solved

Comment: I've seen this. It was something really crazy, like having a closed project selected in the package explorer. Make sure you select the package in package explorer where you want to create the fxml file...

Comment: @James_D Thank you. It still does not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved for me by installing the latest jdk 8u73 and by adding the new build path in eclipse

Ps : sorry for my english

Mounir (France)

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by referencing the JavaFX library to the project. One way to do that is to right-click the project folder in Eclipse, then select Build Path -> Add External Archive.

The JavaFX archive, named `jfxrt.jar` is located in the directory `jre\lib\ext` of your JDK directory.

Surprisingly, the JavaFX libraries are not automatically linked in a JavaFX project... This operation also allows to build JavaFX sample projects, which otherwise don't compile.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this problem because I was under the impression that JavaFX was bundled with Java 8, but that's not true (or maybe not always true) for OpenJDK. Installing the **openjfx** package solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same problem when using e(fx)clipse 3.0. In my situation, changing to version 2.4 helped to fix solution with creating new JavaFX projects (it generates .java, .fxml and .css files automatically now) and with adding files to existing projects. Just uninstall 3.0 and try 2.4

Answer (score 1):

Hello I fixed the problem for my case, it was by right click on the project name > Build and Path > Add libraries > User libraries then click on next select your JavaFX libraries .

i suggest to watch this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVn6_2KuYbM&t=334s

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by right click in `your project -> Build Path-> Add external archives`
Then select the path of scene builder like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\runtime\jre\lib\ext`. In this path now select `jfxrt.jar` and it's done.