# JavaFX FXML application missing from new project dialog.

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have added the package e(fx)clipse to eclipse. When I try to open a new JavaFX FXML project the option to for the JavaFX FXML project is not there.

Can anyone tell me how to get that option in the new project dialog.

Thanks

Carl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot create FXML file in javafx project in eclipse ide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065468/cannot-create-fxml-file-in-javafx-project-in-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, select Help→Install New Software.

Select `All Available Sites` for the `Work with:` field at the top, in the filter field enter `e(fx)clipse`, and install the package `e(fx)clipse - IDE`.

[image]

Restart Eclipse.

You'll now find JavaFX under New→Other

[image]